# How to set data in jsGrid using Express in NodeJs

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, handlebars.js, jsgrid

I want to use jsGrid to display some data retrieved previously from an Express app in this way:

```
app.get('/my-route/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const myData = await Data.getData();
    // Example of output expected: myData  = [{name: 'John', age: '50'}, {name:'Jay', age: '20'}]
    res.render('myPage', { myData });
  } catch (err) {
    /* ... */
  }
});
```

How can I set the "data" parameter in jsGrid? I'm using handlebars to build the templates, and I can't get the value in a `<script>` tag

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
      /* ... Other options ... */
      data: {{myData}} // <-This doesn't works because handlebars doesn't work in the <script> 
      /* ... Other options ... */
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm doing an approach having a hidden input with the value of myData like <input id="myData" type="hidden" value="{{myData}}"> to get the value with jQuery: var dataInScriptTag = $("#myData").val(). Sadly, I'm getting "[object Object]" as a result, not the Object itself to manipulate it.